# better way distribute apps

Tags: 12.04

Is there a way I can get the installed apps, drivers and media drivers etc I have installed on my current machine as a install file or separate?

I use to use APTonCD but this failed today.

I need a better way to do this, and if I added a app on one pc to be able to place that on a flash/cd and install the app on another system.

I have a few pc that are not connected to internet, and the internet is slow on those that are connected.

Having to download updates, apps, plugins and all those again on each pc or even when redoing a pc is time consuming and that frustrates me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the package files on the internet connected computer to others from `/var/cache/apt/archives` then install the .deb files with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` or by doing the below

To replicate the exact packages installed on one machine or another do this (I think if you've copied over the debs, it won't need to download anything, but I maybe wrong):

```
#source machine:
dpkg –get-selection | grep -v deinstall > dpkg-get.txt

#target machine:
dpkg –clear-selections
cat dpkg-get.txt | dpkg –set-selections
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: Any way to this faster? Lets say i downloaded gimp, and want to install gimp on all pcs, but only gimp?

Comment: just copy the gimp .deb (and any dependencies) to the `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder then try `apt-get install gimp`.  I'm pretty sure apt-get looks in that folder first before trying to connect and download anythin

Comment: Have you thought about just putting your computers on a local network and having the internet connected machine act as a local repository for the others?  That way an `apt-get update` would be propogated to the others.  I think it would just involve editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to your local machine instead of the internet

Comment: What program can i use if i want to make customised install disk for my other pcs? I would be able to install other programs that is not on the system from such a disk right?